# provideRouter vs RouterModule.forRoot in angular

Tags: angular, routes

I have seen different ways to setup routes in angular application

In some examples,

- it shows to setup a routing module as mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#milestone-2-routing-module)
  i.e `RouterModule.forRoot` in `app.module.ts`
- other, it shows to setup using config file with `provideRouter`- you can see example [here](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial#import-providerouter-from-angularrouter)

My questions, when do we use what and what is the recommended to use when building a web app ?

I am expecting the recommended approach to the question

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of Angular you are using. Assuming you are using Angular 14+, it will also depend on if you are using the standalone way of building your app without modules, or if you choose to use modules. Before v14, modules was the only way. Both ways accomplish the same thing.

For modules, you would use `RouterModule.forRoot`, as [shown here](https://v16.angular.io/guide/router-tutorial#define-your-routes).

For standalone, you would usee `provideRouter`, as [shown here](https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#defining-a-basic-route).

I would recommend going with the newer way, using standalone. There are many benefits. However, if you are working on a large app that would need to be migrated from modules to standalone, in order to use `provideRouter`, then I would be cautious. Ultimately, updating your app is beneficial, but there is no immediate rush since we will have backwards compatibility for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1):

**RouterModule.forRoot(routes: Routes) :**

- **Purpose**: Used in the root AppModule to configure the main routing
  module for your entire Angular application.
- **When to Use**: This is the primary and most common way to set up routing in Angular. It provides a central location to define your application's routes and throughout the application.

**Example :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, AboutComponent],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [], // Usually no providers are needed for root routing
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**provideRouter(routes: Routes, withModule?: boolean) :**

- **Purpose:** Provides a more granular way to configure routing for specific parts of your application (feature modules).
- **When to Use:** Use this approach when you have large applications with feature modules that have their own routing needs. This helps with code organization and tree-shaking for smaller bundle sizes.

**Example :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

const featureRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent, AboutComponent],
  imports: [provideRouter(featureRoutes)], // Use provideRouter here
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [] 
})
export class FeatureModule { }
```

**Key difference**

RouterModule.forRoot is used for the root AppModule, while provideRouter is used for feature modules.

RouterModule.forRoot makes routing services globally available, while provideRouter provides them within the specific module where it's used.

Comment: Do you have references for this? Your claim that `provideRouter` is for feature routes is incorrect. `provideRouter` should only be used in the root of the application and not in features. See the documentation here: https://angular.io/api/router/provideRouter